# UIbutton IBOutlet to nib

Tags: ios

I have a nib file with a UIView with a class created by me. on the view I have a UIButton linked to the .h file. The connection is done, but when on my .m file I want to change something on my UIButton nothing happens. One of my methods does this:

```
[self.ButtonFacebook setTitle:@"Invite" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but the title doesn't change. the same for alpha, hidden, etc. And the method does get called. Why is this?

Comment: assert(self.ButtonFacebook); assert(self.ButtonFacebook.superview);

Comment: sorry what? I don't understand that code

Comment: `assert(self.ButtonFacebook)` means `if(self.ButtonFacebook == nil) abort()` IN 99% of the cases, the outlet isn't set correctly.